# Removing Data from a Dictionary

Tags: python

I am looking to get rid of movies that don't have a budget, which means they are equal to 0. To do that I started by identifying how many there were in the data.

```
num_no_budgets = 0

for movie_data in imdb_data:
    movie = movie_data['budget']
    if movie == 0:
        num_no_budgets += 1
        
print(num_no_budgets)
```

This tells me that there are 5696 movies in the data without a budget. Then I created a set to store the data in and checked the length of the set to confirm the amount matched the 5696.

```
no_budget_movies = set()
for movie_data in imdb_data:
    if movie_data['budget'] == 0:
        no_budget_movies.add(movie_data['id'])
len(no_budget_movies)
```

The length matched so I created a function to remove those from the data:

```
def remove_nobudget_movies(data):
no_budget_data = []
for data_point in data:
    if data_point['id'] in no_budget_movies:
        no_budget_data.append(data_point)
    return no_budget_data
```

However, when I run this and then check the length, I get 0. I'm sure there is something small here that I'm not doing right.

Comment: It seems like you have some indentation errors.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very complicated, below something that should do the same, in a simpler way:

```
#Init your lists
budget_movies = []
no_budget_movies = []

#To get rid of potential duplicates:
#imdb_data = list(set(imdb_data))

for movie_data in imdb_data:
    #If no budget just add in no budget list
    if movie_data['budget'] == 0:
        no_budget_movies.append(movie_data)
    #Else add in budget list
    else: 
        budget_movies.append(movie_data)

#Compute the length
print (len(no_budget_movies))
print (len(budget_movies))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing indentation:

```
def remove_nobudget_movies(data):
    no_budget_data = []
    for data_point in data:
        if data_point['id'] in no_budget_movies:
            no_budget_data.append(data_point)
    return no_budget_data
```